# How to stop Vscode from destroying my pdf when I have a typo in the code

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, vscode

So I use vscode to write up most of my assignments, and sometimes I need to use tikz figures, and to make that process easier I use tikzfig and tikzit. At times, I edit the tikz files directly without the tikzit interface, but if I miss a semi colon and then try and compile vscode destroys my whole pdf, and I get an error code saying I have an invalid pdf structure. Does anyone know how to stop this from happening, other than just becoming a perfect coder who makes no mistakes?

Comment: Are you using LaTeX Workshop extension?

Comment: Yes I am using latex workshop

Comment: Try adding a step to back up your pdf to the recipe and see if that works. You can also try to add the ``--halt-on-error`` to the pdftex step. I don't have LaTeX currently installed to give you a full sample. Check recipes docs here: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-recipes

Comment: Im unsure of what the recipe is or how to add stuff to it Im being completely honest

Comment: Becoming a perfect coder is probably the best option. It is not expected that you don't make any mistakes, but it _is_ expected when you make a mistake that you can find a way to fix it. You need to do that anyway, otherwise your TikZ figure will be missing or wrong.

Comment: @Marjin I can find and correct mistakes, but I don't see them until vscode spits out an error, usually this isn't issue, but in this case when it spits out an error my whole pdf gets destroyed and I have to copy the corrected code over to an entirely different project

Comment: Can't you delete the corrupted pdf and let it get rebuilt from scratch?

Comment: @Teepeemm no it will not let me do this for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't type this as a comment, so try this to create a backup of your pdf before each run. I'm assuming you are running this through LaTeX Workshop:

1. Open VS Code settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then search for `Open User Settings (JSON)`)
2. Look for `latex-workshop.latex.tools` and add a new tool to the end of the list (if you are not on Windows, replace `copy` with the proper copy command, `cp` for Linux/mac):

   ```
   {
       "name": "backup",
       "command": "copy",
       "args": [
           "%DOC%.pdf",
           "%DOC%-bkp.pdf"
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Look for `latex-workshop.latex.recipes` and add the `backup` tool to it. For example, you can modify the default `pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex × 2` as:

   ```
       {
       "name": "backup ➞ pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex × 2",
       "tools": [
           "backup",
           "pdflatex",
           "bibtex",
           "pdflatex",
           "pdflatex"
       ]
   }
   ```

This will create a backup file each time you run your recipe.